# StructureMap .ForConcreteType<T>().Configure.SetProperty configuration does not play ball with BuildUp logic

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap

Trying to figure out how to configure StructureMap for property setter injection. I have scenarios where I resolve an instance through the container as well as scenarios where I get an instance elsewhere and then call the congainer.BuildUp() feature.

I have included a sample set of classes below where I want to configure injection for the concrete type Bar. If I use the different options marked 1)-5) below I will get different behaviors from StructureMap. Some of the cases must fail since they are incomplete but all cases where I configure injection on both the Foo and the Qux properties should work. They do not. Especially the .BuildUp() feature does not work.

Rather than me explaining each outcome in detail perhaps some StructureMap wiz out there can be so kind as to point out the flaw in my logic and/or run the sample code?

There are other work around configurations I guess but I'd like to be able to be explicit in what injections I expect on Bar.

Thanks in advance!

```
[TestClass]
public class StructureMapTests
{
    public interface IFoo { }
    public interface IBaz { }
    public interface IQux { }

    private class Foo : IFoo { }

    private class Baz : IBaz { }

    private class Qux : IQux { }

    private class Bar
    {
        public IFoo Foo { get; set; }

        public IFoo FooSomething { get; set; }

        public IBaz Baz { get; set; }

        public IQux Qux { get; set; }
    }

    Container Container;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Configure_StructureMap()
    {
        Container = new Container();
        Container.Configure(x =>
            {
                x.For<IFoo>().Use<Foo>();
                x.For<IBaz>().Use<Baz>();
                x.For<IQux>().Use<Qux>();

                x.FillAllPropertiesOfType<IBaz>();
                x.SetAllProperties(policy =>
                {
                    policy.NameMatches(name => name.EndsWith("Something"));
                });

                // 1)
                //x.ForConcreteType<Bar>().Configure.SetProperty(r => r.Foo = new Foo());
                //x.ForConcreteType<Bar>().Configure.Setter<IQux>().IsTheDefault();

                // 2)
                //x.ForConcreteType<Bar>().Configure.SetProperty(r => r.Foo = new Foo());

                // 3)
                //x.ForConcreteType<Bar>().Configure.Setter<IQux>().IsTheDefault();

                // 4)
                //x.ForConcreteType<Bar>().Configure.Setter<IQux>().IsTheDefault().SetProperty(r => r.Foo = new Foo());

                // 5)
                //x.ForConcreteType<Bar>().Configure.SetProperty(r => r.Foo = new Foo()).Setter<IQux>().IsTheDefault();
            });
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Resolve_Bar_through_container()
    {
        var bar = Container.GetInstance<Bar>();

        Debug.WriteLine("Resolve:");
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Foo is {0}null.", bar.Foo == null ? "" : "not "));
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("FooSomething is {0}null.", bar.FooSomething == null ? "" : "not "));
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Baz is {0}null.", bar.Baz == null ? "" : "not "));
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Qux is {0}null.", bar.Qux == null ? "" : "not "));

        Assert.IsTrue(bar.Foo != null && bar.FooSomething != null && bar.Baz != null && bar.Qux != null);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void BuildUp_instance_of_bar()
    {
        var bar = new Bar();
        Container.BuildUp(bar);

        Debug.WriteLine("Build up:");
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Foo is {0}null.", bar.Foo == null ? "" : "not "));
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("FooSomething is {0}null.", bar.FooSomething == null ? "" : "not "));
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Baz is {0}null.", bar.Baz == null ? "" : "not "));
        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Qux is {0}null.", bar.Qux == null ? "" : "not "));

        Assert.IsTrue(bar.Foo != null && bar.FooSomething != null && bar.Baz != null && bar.Qux != null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OnCreationForAll` method for registering the properties of `Bar`:

```cs
container.Configure(r => r.For<Bar>().OnCreationForAll(bar =>
{
    bar.Foo = container.GetInstance<IFoo>();
    bar.FooSomething = container.GetInstance<IFoo>();
    bar.Baz = container.GetInstance<IBaz>();
    bar.Qux = container.GetInstance<IQux>();
}));
```